# Create KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> from columns in a single data row

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-identity, dapper

I have the following table in Sql Server that stores the permissions the Foreign Key `UserId` has to the Foreign Keyed `BlogId`. What I would like to do is write a query with Dapper that takes each column after `BlogId` and returns it as a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserPermission] (
    [UserPermissionId]     INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [BlogId]               INT NOT NULL,
    [UserId]               INT NOT NULL,
    [CanCreateNewPosts]    BIT NOT NULL,
    [CanEditExistingPosts] BIT NOT NULL,
    [CanDeleteExistingPosts] BIT NOT NULL,
    [CanPublishDraftPosts] BIT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UserPermission] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserPermissionId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPermission_Blog] FOREIGN KEY ([BlogId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Blog] ([BlogId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_UserPermission_User] FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([UserId])
);
```

I would like to query via Dapper like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM [Permission] WHERE UserId = @UserId";
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, bool>> results = await connection.QueryAsync(
        sql,
        new { UserId = this.userId });
}

var p1 = results.First();
var p2 = results.Skip(1).First();
```

In the above example, I would like `p1` to result in a `KeyValuePair` with the Key being `CanCreateNewPosts` and the Value being the column value, either true or false. Same applies with `p2`, where the Key would be `CanEditExistingPosts`, with it's corresponding value.

The underlying need for this is to simplify transforming the record into a list of Claims in Identity, one claim per column.

I looked at `splitOn:`, to try and split after the `UserId` column but that doesn't seem like it's what I want. It would require n-generic arguments for each column I split. Ideally I'd like to add columns to this table in the future and my security/data/servicing layer just handles turning it into a Claim - letting me just focus on the Controller Action that needs to check for the claim. Having the query and Dapper return map the column-name/values into a collection of `KeyValuePairs` would facilitate that need for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operation to transform columns into column values. Here's an example for your particular case:

```
SELECT u.BlogId, u.permission
FROM UserPermissions up
UNPIVOT
(
    permission for perms in (
        CanCreateNewPosts, 
        CanEditExistingPosts, 
        CanDeleteExistingPosts, 
        CanPublishDraftPosts
    )
) u;
```

Comment: Close; what I essentially wanted was the column names to be returned as keys, and the column values returned as my value for that key. So I'd have a KeyValuePair for instance with the key being "CanCreateNewPost" and a value of "1". Not including BlogId, UserId and UserPermissionId